# White box in JOGL scene with orthographic projection

Tags: textures, jogl, orthographic

I am using a recent version of JOGL 2.0

My scene is set up with Orthographic projection and I am trying to add a texture to bottom of the scene. The texture is a 1600 x 100 PNG file.

If I use a 1000 x 1000 PNG file the texture renders ok but when I use a 1600 x 100 texture I get a white box.

I have set up the orthographic projection using

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);

gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

I am loading the texture using

```
texture = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("image.png") ,false);
```

I am drawing the texture using

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
TextureCoords tc = texture.getImageTexCoords();

texture.bind(gl);

gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

gl.glTexCoord2d(tc.left(),tc.top());gl.glVertex2d(0.0,0.1);     
gl.glTexCoord2d(tc.left(),tc.bottom());gl.glVertex2d(0.0,0.0);      
gl.glTexCoord2d(tc.right(),tc.bottom());gl.glVertex2d(1.0,0.0);     
gl.glTexCoord2d(tc.right(),tc.top()); gl.glVertex2d(1.0,0.1);

gl.glEnd();
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a white box is because your graphics card does support such a big image. 1600 x 1600 pixels is too big, and 1600 x 100 is too big as well by modern standards. I suggest you use 1024 x 128.

For maximum compatibility I suggest you use textures with power-of-two. For example 32 x 64, 128 x 512 or even 1024 x 1024. Just because a number is divisible by two doesn't mean power-of-two. A power-of-two is when you 2^x.

Tip to find power-of-two-numbers (calculator): Just enter [2] [*] [2] [=] [=] [=]... Where [] represents your input.